# How to I import public .pem dsa key into c# code?

Tags: c#, windows, linux, encryption

I'm trying to import a public DSA key in .pem format, generated by openssl into c# code to verify signatures using DSACryptoServiceProvider.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an x509Certificate2 from a PEM source (there are constructors that take a string filename).  At that point, you should be able to use that with the crypto provider.